# Can anyone help me convert my data frame into a time series object without using my date format?

Tags: r, date, datetime, time-series, forecasting

I'm trying to convert a data frame that contains 2 variables (date and unit sales) into a time series object so that I can later on produce a forecast. After I reformat the data to a time series object the dates were changed into a number, I've tried to change them back into regular dates  using advice from other related questions on Stackoverflow but I wasn`t able to make it work, any advice would be more than appreciated!

Also my data is recorded at weekly intervals and it spans from late March 2019 to late March 2021, is there any way I could transform the weekly observations into monthly observations? Thank you!

```
###Import data

Unit.sales <- structure(list(
  Date = c(
    "30/03/2019",
    "06/04/2019",
    "13/04/2019",
    "20/04/2019",
    "27/04/2019",
    "04/05/2019",
    "11/05/2019",
    "18/05/2019",
    "25/05/2019",
    "01/06/2019"
  ),
  Units = c(
    967053.4,
    633226.9,
    523264,
    473914.2,
    418087.5,
    504342.2,
    477819,
    415650,
    406972.3,
    429791.4
  )
), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame") 

###Convert to time series

Unit.sales$Date <- as.Date(Unit.sales$Date, format='%d/%m/%Y')

date <- Unit.sales$Date

units <- Unit.sales$Units

unit.sales <- data.frame(date, units)

unit.sales.ts <- ts(unit.sales$units, 
                    start = min(unit.sales$date),
                    frequency = 1/7)
unit.sales.ts

###Convert times series to show regular dates
as.Date(as.numeric(time(unit.sales.ts)))
```

After running the last line of code this is the error that I get

```
> as.Date(as.numeric(time(unit.sales.ts)))
Error in as.Date.numeric(as.numeric(time(unit.sales.ts))) : 
  'origin' must be supplied
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error. And `sales_data.ts` is not the same as `sales.data.ts` I'm wondering if you have a couple of different objects with very similar names?

Comment: Thank you for catching that, I probably messed up when I wrote the question as I was fiddling with the code itself before posting it. I have corrected it now and there should not be any "sales_data.ts" object left in the code anymore. akrun pointed out in the answers that the origin argument starting in 1970-01-01 was missing . Would you know how I would go about integrating that resulting vector back into the time series object? I'm sorry for all the questions I'm new to R and I just completed the classes on codeacademy but none of them went into working with time series objects.

Answer (score 0):

With a `numeric` input, specify the `origin`

```
as.Date(as.numeric(time(unit.sales.ts)), origin = '1970-01-01')
```

-output

```
[1] "2019-03-30" "2019-04-06" "2019-04-13" "2019-04-20" "2019-04-27" "2019-05-04" "2019-05-11" "2019-05-18" "2019-05-25" "2019-06-01"
```

Comment: Thank you very much akrun! I'm new to R and the courses I did never really went into time series objects and at the knowledge level that I'm at I found other online resources to be quite confusing or  to be talking mostly about monthly data which seems to make things simpler. I hope you`ll have a great day!

Comment: @Petru The problem had nothing to do wiuth R's time series function, but was rather due to the fact that there are two different versions of `as.Date`: one for character values and the otehr for numeric values. Those two functions have different parameter requirements.